# Flask + gevent: possible sockets leaks (in the CLOSE_WAIT state)

Tags: python, sockets, flask, gevent

I have a possible connections leak, when doing streaming with flask and gevent.

Many connections on the server side are staying (after they are closed on the client side) in the `CLOSE_WAIT` state.

It happens not for all clients, but only for some of them (but for that clients it happens in 100% cases).

I am using standard Flask streaming code, nothing special, so I say that the problem is general.

Here is my code:

```
@app.route('/', defaults={'path': ''}, methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def catch_all(path):
     session_id = 'tettris'
     if session_id not in sessions:
         session = Session()
         sessions[session_id] = session
     else:
         session = sessions[session_id]

     session.start()
     queue = register_queue()
     def events():
         try:
             if queue:
                 while True:
                     for _, data in queue:
                         yield data
         finally:
             # THIS POINT HERE IS NEVER BEING REACHED
             # FOR SOME CLIENTS, becase the connection
             # is getting stuck in the CLOSE_WAIT state

             deregister_queue(queue)
             if len(queues) == 0:
                 session.kill()
                 del sessions[session_id]

  return Response(events(), content_type='text/event-stream')
```

As you can see, the code is trivial and pretty standard.

I suppose that there should be some sort of a race condition somewhere, because as I said, not all connections end up in the `CLOSE_WAIT` state.

I suppose, that it depends on the TCP/IP stack of the client.

Comment: How is the `while True:` loop exited?

Comment: I suspect removing that will fix this issue.

Comment: @VPfB: It's a standard technique: when the descriptor is closed and you are trying to write to it, you'll get an exception, and then you will leave the loop. See for example this http://flask.pocoo.org/snippets/116/ , as I said, it is a common thing, and of course it is not the root of the problem with the CLOSE_WAIT leak

Comment: @IgorChubin Thank you for the explanation. I did not know about this interaction between Flask and a streaming view function from briefly reading the docs.

Comment: It could be issue from proxy server as well which fails to tell back end to close connection. Check if your proxy server cpu usage goes high when your close_wait goes high.

Comment: @jayprakashstar: There is no proxy in this installation

Comment: Hi @IgorChubin did you find any solution to this problem? I am facing the same, but in my case the worker is `gthread` (from `gunicorn`),...the server stops receiving requests suddenly. `netstat -nap | grep PORT_NUMBER` shows there are so many `CLOSE_WAIT`s.

Comment: @hafiz031: I didn't solve the problem; I just reported it upstream, and it was accepted as a bug; and what I did, I just switched that project where I had it, to Go, and I must admit (being a Flask-fan even), it is day and night. So I don't even know what happened to this bug, but it is possible that it is still there